# Cant seem to find the issue i am having with this code. Getting Error code "for i in images_per_class: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python

## loop over the images in each sub-folder

```
for i in images_per_class:
    for x in range(1, images_per_class + 1):
```

Error code

```
for i in images_per_class:
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Maybe you want `for i in range(images_per_class)`?

Comment: just want to loop over images in each sub folder. But i was getting this error message

Comment: You need to add more of your code in your question to be helped.